# Oracle DB "Other users" within a schema connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My question is kind of straightforward and so should be the answer.

Talking about ORACLE databases in SQL Developer, we can create connections to users' schemes.

The connection needs to specify the username and the password, and that allows to access the schema of that user. Below the connection, I usually see all the elements of the schema shown within folders like *Tables*, *Views*, *Indexes*, *Packages* and so on.

But then I also see the folder *Other Users* just next to those from above. This folder contains a list of other usernames (different from the one you are currently connecting to). Exploring each of these, you see in turn a schema (like a set of elements as from above).

What is this design about? Are they different users sharing the same schema (tables, views, packages, indexes etc..) but with different grants? When we do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection details determines which SCHEMA you will be browsing when you expand the connection tree.

The other users node allows you to browse additional schemas. Your connection user's privileges will determine what you can or can't see in other schemas.

A database object is owned by a single user, or exists in a single schema (which is really the collection of objects owned by a user.) There are no shared objects.